# Is there any sufficient condition under which the hadamard product of two square matrices is invertible?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Is there any sufficient condition under which the hadamard product of two square matrices is invertible ?

Answer (score 5):

Schur product theorem states that for symmetric positive semidefinite matrices $A$, $B$, we have

$$\det(A \circ B) \geq \det(A) \det(B).$$

Hence a sufficient condition cound be both $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive definite.

Hence $\det(A)\det(B) > 0$

Edit:

Using Oppenheim's inequality, $$\det(A \circ B) \geq \det(A) \prod_{i=1}^nB_{ii}$$

for symmetic positive semidefinite matrices.
One sufficient condition is  that $A$ is symmetric positive definite, $B$ is symmetric positive semidefnite and all diagonal entries of $B$ is non-zero.

Similarly, we can have $B$ is symmetric positive definite, $A$ is symmetric positive semidefinite and all diagonal entries of $A$ is non-zero.

Comment: What about using Oppenheim’s Inequality.

Comment: Oppenheim's inequality require $A$ and $B$ to be positive definite as well right?

Comment: I think it is for symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. Please check https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ae5f/2ce128b0398ec796182ff05008ca6ccf877d.pdf

Comment: Edited the answer to use Oppenheim's Inequality.